# How to write simple TCP sender/receiver on socket

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, tcp, network-programming

I want to create a simple communication object that will connect to socket 
( = ip@port) and will be able to send and receive byte array to/from this socket.

I don't want to close the connection between my two machine - i want to keep the tcp connection until i'll close the connection manually

1. I know about the 'TcpClient' and the 'TcpListener' but i don't know witch of them i need to use to my case.
2. How i can listen to the same socket and be able to send byte[] to the same port on my case and still be able to not miss any packages that i need to receive ?

Comment: Have you not tried the samples from MSDN for TcpClient / TcpListener ?

Comment: i tried but i still can't be sure that there are no missing packages

Comment: Please post your code - what makes you think there are missing packets ? TCP is a reliable connection orientated protocol so there shouldn't be.

Comment: You have asked more than 400 questions. Please read [ask], share your research and explain very explicitly with what part you need help. It seems like you're just looking for a sockets tutorial, of which there are plenty on the web.

Comment: @Yanshof - You may like to upvote the answer if it helped you! Please see how to upvote an answer here -> https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. I know about the 'TcpClient' and the 'TcpListener' but i don't know
>      witch of them i need to use to my case.

Even a simple search on the web would have given you numerous answers. Anyways, TcpClient is for the client side of TCP/IP connections. TcpListener is for the server side of TCP/IP connections.

> 2. How i can listen to the same socket and be able to send byte[] to the same port on my case and still be able to not miss any packages
>      that i need to receive ?

You won't miss any packets, since your underlying transport protocol is TCP.

For TcpClient/client example ---> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_6

For TcpListener/server example ---> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_6